# Override default indexes in AspNetCore.Identity tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1, ef-core-2.1

I'm developing a multi-tenant application in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. I'm utilizing `AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` framework for user management. I want to add a **unique index** combining `NormalizedName` with `TenantId` in `Role` Table. Also, in the user table `NormalizedUserName` with `TenantId` in `User` table.

This doesn't let me create that index since identity creates a default unique indexes for Role table `RoleNameIndex` and `UserNameIndex` for User table. What is the best way to configure that in `OnModelCreating` method in EF Core?

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedUserName, u.TenantId }).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique(true);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedName, u.TenantId }).HasName("RoleNameIndex").IsUnique(true);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fluent API currently does not provide a way to remove a previously defined index (like the indexes in question defined by the base `OnModelCreating`), but mutable entity metadata does via [`IMutableEntityType.RemoveIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imutableentitytype.removeindex?view=efcore-2.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IMutableEntityType_RemoveIndex_System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyList_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_IProperty__) method.

It can be used like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
{
    builder.Metadata.RemoveIndex(new[] { builder.Property(u => u.NormalizedUserName).Metadata });

    builder.HasIndex(u => new { u.NormalizedUserName, u.TenantId }).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique();
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(builder =>
{
    builder.Metadata.RemoveIndex(new[] { builder.Property(r => r.NormalizedName).Metadata });

    builder.HasIndex(r => new { r.NormalizedName, r.TenantId }).HasName("RoleNameIndex").IsUnique();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can actually, unless you don't call `base.OnModelCreating` in your override. However, you'd then be responsible for all the Identity fluent config. You can see what you're dealing with [here on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/EF/IdentityDbContext.cs).

The only thing to be aware of, if you go down that path, is that you'll need to watch for changes to the fluent config and make sure you add those into yours as they are introduced.

Comment: Yes. Actually I'm overriding onModel Creating method for the changes.